# Linq Join on multiple columns not working

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a LINQ join I'm doing with multiple columns, but it's not properly joining.

I want to join two tables based on their name, and the value of their primary email address.

```
var batchId = 500000002;
var companyQuery = Companies 
    .Where(x => x.ImportCompany == null) // ImportCompany is a subtype of Company, i want to match on non-ImportCompany
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.Party.Name, //company is a subtype of Party
        x.Party.EmailAccounts.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsPrimary).Address
    });

var importedQuery = ImportCompanies
    .Where(x => x.ImportBatch_Id == batchId)
    .Select(imported => new
    {
        imported.Id,
        imported.Company.Party.Name,
        imported.Company.Party.EmailAccounts.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsPrimary).Address
    });

var query = importedQuery
    .Join(companyQuery, x => new { x.Name, x.Address }, x => new { x.Name, x.Address }, 
         (imported, existing) => new { Imported = imported.Id, Existing = existing.Id })
    .ToList();
```

`query` is returning no results.

My values are set up like so:

```
ImportedCompany Record | Company Record
---------------------------------------
Name = "Test"          | Name = "Test"
Address = null         | Address = null
```

Why is my join not returning any results? Is there some weirdness with the null address, or is it because address is in a child table that something's getting messed up?

Comment: What is address is not null?  In SQL Server, `null = null` returns `null`, which is not `TRUE` and the join will fail.

Comment: @DStanley ok, i changed it to do `?? "A"` for both the addresses and it seemed to work. So I just need to provide some other "null" case like string empty i guess. Thanks!

Comment: @DLeh did you solve this? If so please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing this line

```
x.Party.EmailAccounts.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsPrimary).Address
```

to this

```
Address = x.Party.EmailAccounts.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsPrimary).Address ?? string.Empty
```